# can't Locate html menu elements properly (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create jquery menu but my code doesn't work and when i hover over menu elements looks like this blue thing at the right of the browser.

[Photo of the Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEnop.png)

When I copy list elements from [jquery menu](https://jqueryui.com/menu/)  
it works but mine doesn't.here is my code **I copied all since I am not sure whether The problem is place of the script or link tags**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").menu();
})
```

```css
#menu{
  max-width: 150px;
}
.Container{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Container">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Rome</li>
      <ul>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>Economy</li>
        <li>Politics</li>
      </ul>
      <li>-</li>
      <li>British</li>
      <ul>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>Economy</li>
        <li>Politics</li>
      </ul>
      <li>-</li>
      <li>Ottoman</li>
      <ul>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>Economy</li>
        <li>Politics</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu").menu();
  })
```

```css
#menu{
  max-width: 150px;
}
.Container{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div class="Container">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><div>Rome</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div>History</div></li>
          <li><div>Economy</div></li>
          <li><div>Politics</div></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li><div>British</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div>History</div></li>
          <li><div>Economy</div></li>
          <li><div>Politics</div></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li><div>Ottoman</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div>History</div></li>
          <li><div>Economy</div></li>
          <li><div>Politics</div></li>
        </ul></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here you go, actually you didnt wrote it in the format that [jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/menu/) menu need.

Comment: Now I see , I have been closing the <li> tag right after the rome thats Why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is invalid. A `ul` can't be a child of a `ul` - you need to nest the sub-menus in the top-level `li`'s

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").menu();
})
```

```css
#menu{
  max-width: 150px;
}
.Container{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Container">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Rome
      <ul>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>Economy</li>
        <li>Politics</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>British
      <ul>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>Economy</li>
        <li>Politics</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Ottoman</li>
      <ul>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>Economy</li>
        <li>Politics</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```